# Merging Two Matrixes... in LISP

Tags: lisp

```
(defun merge-matrix (matrix-1 matrix-2)
    (if (not (or (eql (matrix-rows matrix-1) (matrix-rows matrix-2)) (null matrix-1) (null matrix-2))) (error "Invalid dimensions."))
    (cond
        ((null matrix-1) (copy-tree matrix-2))
        ((null matrix-2) (copy-tree matrix-1))
        (t (let ((result (copy-tree matrix-1)))
                 (dotimes (i (matrix-rows matrix-1))
                     (setf (nth i result) (nconc (nth i result) (nth i matrix-2))))
                 result))))
```

> > (merge-matrix '((3 1) (1 3)) '((4 2) (1 1)))

*** - EVAL: variable NULL has no value

I receive an error like that how I can fix the problem, thanks

Comment: What does MATRIX-ROWS look like? If I use (defun matrix-rows (matrix) (length matrix)) for instance I get the answer ((3 1 4 2) (1 3 1 1)).

Comment: What the function supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

The OP's code works for me. However I felt motivated to improve it and
I implemented the same idea (but a bit more powerful).

The semantics are the same as Matlab's vertcat.
The function appends all arguments into one big matrix.

Note that due to the declarations my code should be super efficient.

```
(deftype mat ()
  "Non-square matrices. Last index is columns, i.e. row-major order."
  `(simple-array single-float 2))

(defun are-all-elements-typep (type ls)
  (reduce #'(lambda (b x) (and b (typep x type)))
      ls))

(defun are-all-matrix-heights-equalp (ls)
  (let ((first-height (array-dimension (first ls) 0)))
    (reduce #'(lambda (b x) (and b
                (= first-height
                   (array-dimension x 0))))
       ls)))

(defun vertcat (&rest rest)
  (declare (type cons rest))
  (unless (are-all-elements-typep 'mat rest)
    (break "At least one of the arguments isn't a matrix."))
  (unless (are-all-matrix-heights-equalp rest)
    (break "All Matrices must have the same number of rows."))
  (let* ((height (array-dimension (first rest) 0))
     (widths (mapcar #'(lambda (mat) (array-dimension mat 1)) rest))
     (result (make-array (list height
                   (reduce #'+ widths))
                 :element-type 'single-float))
     (current-width 0))
    (dotimes (m (length rest))
      (let ((e (elt rest m)))
    (destructuring-bind (y x) (array-dimensions e)
     (dotimes (j y)
       (dotimes (i x)
         (setf (aref result j (+ current-width i))
           (aref e j i))))
     (incf current-width (elt widths m)))))
    (the mat result)))

#+nil
(let ((a (make-array '(2 3)
             :initial-contents '((1s0 2s0 3s0)
                     (2s0 4s0 5s0))
             :element-type 'single-float))
      (b (make-array '(2 2)
             :initial-contents '((6s0 7s0)
                     (9s0 8s0))
             :element-type 'single-float)))
  (vertcat a b a))
;=> #2A ((1.0 2.0 3.0 6.0 7.0 1.0 2.0 3.0) (2.0 4.0 5.0 9.0 8.0 2.0 4.0 5.0))
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message you're getting suggests that lisp is trying to treat one of your calls to `null` as a variable. I was able to replicate this behavior by defining `matrix-rows` like Frank Shearar did and deleting the parentheses around the `((null matrix-1) (copy-tree matrix-2))` s-expression, for example. I'd suggest you check your parentheses, either manually or using something like [SLIME](http://common-lisp.net/project/slime/), which gave me a warning when I tried to compile the function.